# Why does this query ask me to declare the table when I already have?

Tags: sql, t-sql

My Issue is that the last query in this sproc is saying that I need to declare @N but I already have any ideas?

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (Smpinstanceid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

    INSERT INTO @t

    (Smpinstanceid)

    SELECT  t.SmpInstanceid
    FROM Tasks t
    WHERE t.Completed IS NOT NULL and t.SmpInstanceID is not null

DECLARE @N TABLE
(SMPinstanceid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,[Count] INT)

INSERT INTO @N
(SMPinstanceid,[COUNT])

     SELECT Smpinstanceid,COUNT (Smpinstanceid) AS [Count]
                         FROM   @t
                         GROUP BY Smpinstanceid




            UPDATE Tasks
            SET    StepNum = @n.Count
            WHERE Tasks.SmpInstanceID = @n.smpinstanceid
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reference to @n in the update query. You will need to do your update with a subquery, or with a 'from' clause (if this is sql server)

```
update tasks
  SET StepNum = (select Count from @n 
                     where Tasks.SmpInstanceID = @n.smpinstanceid )
```

or

```
update tasks
  set stepnum = n.count
  from tasks
    inner join @n as n
      on (Tasks.SmpInstanceID = n.smpinstanceid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually put the table in your WHERE clause somewhere.

For example:

```
UPDATE T
SET StepNum = n.[Count]
FROM Tasks T
INNER JOIN @n n ON n.SmpInstanceId = T.SmpInstanceId
```

Answer (score 0):

You have @n declared, but it is a table, and not being used in the Update clause.  You need to add it to the Update clause somehow, or you need to change it to not be a table.

```
UPDATE Tasks
SET    StepNum = @n.Count
FROM Tasks
JOIN @n on  Tasks.SmpInstanceID = @n.smpinstanceid
```